# create a shared legend colorbar in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, charts

I am having a matplotlib figures in a wxpython panel and I am having lots of such panels. these panels are arranged such that that for ma matrix.

each figure is having only on 1 axis graphs.

I wanted to create a separate panel for colorbar and want to place it a specific place.

I have seen some example here on stack overflow where for a set of axis/graphs they have created a common legend colorbar, but I am having a different problem where my axis are in different figures and even I want legend colorbar in a different figure. please suggest a solution for this problem

Comment: you may want to show us some example code and explain us where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for stupid question

```
        ax = self.__figlegend.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
        norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(attribute_vals), vmax=max(attribute_vals))
        cbar = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
        cbar.set_label(colorby)
```

I tried something like this,

I have created a dummy axis and then created a colorbar as mentioned above, attribute_vals are the values for my scatter plot